# Cannot convert from 'System.Xml.XmlNode' to 'Google.GData.Client.IExtensionElementFactory

Tags: c#, gdata-api

I'm trying to invite guest to google calendar using GData. I found

http://www.mail-archive.com/google-calendar-help-dataapi@googlegroups.com/msg01759.html

But on the line:

```
entry.ExtensionElements.Add(fragment.FirstChild);
```

I get a compile error saying:

```
Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Xml.XmlNode' to 'Google.GData.Client.IExtensionElementFactory'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself:

```
entry.ExtensionElements.Add(new XmlExtension(fragment.FirstChild));
```